# Question about $O_X$-ideals: why is $\{ y \in X: 1 \notin Q_y \}$ closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X, O_X)$ be a scheme and $Q$ an $O_X$-ideal. I am trying to figure out two details about this and any explanation is appreciated.  Thank you!

1) How come $Y = \{ y \in X: 1 \notin Q_y \}$ a closed subset of $X$?

2) How to show that the cokernel of $0 \to Q \to O_X$ is $0$ outside of $Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both questions are local so you can assume that $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and that $Q\subseteq A$ is an ideal.

1. For a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec} A$ we see that $1\notin Q_{\mathfrak{p}}$ if and only if $Q_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a proper ideal in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, which means that $Q\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. Hence $Y=\{ \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} A \,|\, \mathfrak{p}\supseteq Q \}$, which is closed by definition of Zariski topology.
2. The cokernel of the map $Q\to A$ is $A/Q$ and since localization is exact, we have that $(A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}} = A_{\mathfrak{p}}/Q_{\mathfrak{p}}$. So, if $\mathfrak{p}\notin Y$, then the previous point shows that $Q_{\mathfrak{p}}=A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, and then $(A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$.

Comment: I am not seeing how to deduce that 1. is a local problem, although I'm sure it is. I asked it as a separate question here. If you have any explanation it would be appreciated. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536387/question-about-the-restiction-of-o-x-ideal-of-a-scheme-x-to-an-affine-open?noredirect=1#comment7273050_3536387)

Comment: As in the question that you have linked, I was assuming that the ideal sheaf would be quasicoherent, since that's the standard definition one takes in algebraic geometry. If you assume this, is it clear why the problem is local?